# SwiftUI crashes when using a binding for deep nested values

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I am trying to keep my app contents reactive and up to date with remote data. My values are explored using a `NavigationLink`, but SwiftUI will crash when I'm 2 pages deep and the original item goes away.

To start:

```
class App: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Item] = [
        Item(id: "a", accounts: [
            Account(id: "1"),
            Account(id: "2"),
            Account(id: "3")
        ])
    ]
}
```

```
struct AllItems: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var app: App
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(app.items.indices, id: \.self) { index in
            NavigationLink(destination: ItemView(item: self.$app.items[index])) {
                Text(self.app.items[index].id)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ItemView: View {
    @Binding var item: Item
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(item.accounts.indices, id: \.self) { index in
            NavigationLink(destination: AccountView(item: self.$item.accounts[index])) {
                Text(self.item.accounts[index].id)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct AccountView: View {
    @Binding var account: Account
    var body: some View {
        Text(account.id)
    }
}
```

However, if I am on the AccountView page and `items` becomes empty the app will crash with "Fatal error: Index out of range".

I originally was not using bindings, but then AccountView was not updating when the contents of an Account struct changed, the view did not change. Now by passing bindings, the views do update properly, but it can lead to a crash if the list size changes.

Comment: You can consider approach in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61094219/swiftui-landmarks-app-tutorial-screen-navigates-back-when-toggle-favorite) - the reason has the same origin in your crash and in that case.

Answer (score -1):

yes, if in another part of your code the items becomes empty the app will crash.
When it comes to concurrency/multi-threading/asynchronous etc... you have to take care of it yourself. Using for example, the GCD framework or the Combine functional reactive library to get notified of what is going on and act on it.

Comment: Could you give a starting point/code ?

Answer (score -1):

The following test code shows a possible workaround to prevent crashing when items becomes empty.

```
class Item {
let id: String
var accounts: [Account]
init(id: String, accounts: [Account]) {
    self.id = id
    self.accounts = accounts
}
}

struct Account {
let id: String
}

class App: ObservableObject {
@Published var items: [Item] = [
    Item(id: "item a", accounts: [
        Account(id: "account 1"),
        Account(id: "account 2"),
        Account(id: "account 3")
    ])
]
}

struct ItemView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var app: App
@State var itemNdx: Int
var body: some View {
    itemNdx < self.app.items.count
        ? AnyView(ForEach(app.items[itemNdx].accounts.indices, id: \.self) { index in
            NavigationLink(destination: AccountView(itemNdx: self.itemNdx, accountNdx: index)) {
                Text(self.app.items[self.itemNdx].accounts[index].id)
            }
        })
        : AnyView(EmptyView())
}
}

struct AccountView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var app: App
@State var itemNdx: Int
@State var accountNdx: Int
var body: some View {
    itemNdx < self.app.items.count
        ? AnyView(Text(app.items[itemNdx].accounts[accountNdx].id))
        : AnyView(EmptyView())
}
}

struct AllItems: View {
@EnvironmentObject var app: App
var body: some View {
    ForEach(app.items.indices, id: \.self) { index in
        NavigationLink(destination: ItemView(itemNdx: index)) {
            Text(self.app.items[index].id)
        }
    }
}
}

struct ContentView: View {
// the app is passed in from the SceneDelegate "var app = App()"
@EnvironmentObject var app: App

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        AllItems()
    }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    .onAppear(perform: loadData)
}

func loadData() {
    // this will set the items to empty in 10 seconds
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) {
        self.app.items = []
    }
}
}
```

Comment: That looks unfortunate

Comment: not sure what you mean "That looks unfortunate". This code works, and provides a way around your problem. Did you try it?

Comment: I know it's kinda picky, but I don't prefer code that just works. I rather a solution that makes sense and seems proper. I've found a few other options, that have some pros and cons, but this solutions looks very complicated to simply display a list.

Comment: fair enough. I'd be interested in the solution you find. Let us know.

Comment: I came up with another solution that works cleanly for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61170013/359532